# Adding a space between javascript keywords and parenthesis

Tags: regex, xcode

I want to do a bulk insert of a space between certain JavaScript keywords and the opening parenthesis immediately following them.
The regex I was going to use, is:

```
(if|function|instanceof|return)\(
```

But I can't replace it with a fixed string like

```
this (
```

since it would overwrite the individual keywords.

How do I find just the paren in that regex, such that I can replace it with:
`[blank space](`

I'd want to use a single regex instead of one search expression for each individual keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$N` to refer to the string matched by the `N`th capture group:

```
newstr = str.replace(/(if|function|instanceof|return)\(/g, '$1 (');
```

Comment: That wouldnt really work in XCODE really.  I was trying to do a replace with command + alt + f, so the concept of using javascript to fix this would not be what i am looking for.

Comment: Ideally, i want to find a regex that finds the parenthesis of the results of a regex.... in 1 regex (if possible).

Comment: @Fallenreaper: Did you try to put `$1 (` into Xcode's replacement box? Just verified this to work in Version 6.1.1. Alternatively, you could try `\1 (`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to do this in Javascript.

Comment: @Abecee thats awesome!  I didnt know that `$1` would do that.